# Does the font have to be on the server or on user computer

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am using a font on my website that is not so common, and I was wondering, for the user to see it, is it enough (does it have) to be installed on the server? or it has to be installed on the user's machine?
and how do I know if a font is a free font or not? I would like to use SketchFlow Print

I am using Asp.Net, css 2.
Thanks

Comment: I googled what your question essentially was: "using a font not on users computer" the first result is what you should use. Did you actually have a look around?

Comment: actually I did, but with other words, almost the words in my question...don't think we should discuss google-ing skills though, I got my answer here, and the topic will probably help others too. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS version used depend on the user's browser.

If the user doesn't have the font on his computer, he won't see the font you want him to see.

However, if you use CSS3, you can use [Google's Font (free)](http://www.google.com/webfonts). Take a look at CSS3 `tff`, `eot`, `otf` and `woff` format.

Comment: thanks, I have used your version and it works...I think it is the easiest and pretty elegant too. Thanks

Comment: Your welcome. Also, these fonts are in a CDN (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network). It's very good !

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 contains the @font-face directive which allows you to specify a custom font that will be used to render content in so long as the browser supports the directive.

For all fonts which do not use the @font-face directive (and in browsers which do not support it) the font is rendered by the user's machine with the fonts that they have available. If the font that you specify does not exist on their machine, their browser will default to a different font. One way to help control this is by specifying multiple fonts like this:

```
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Tahoma, Sans-Serif;
```

The browser will attempt to display the first font on the list and descend one by one if it does not support a given font until it finds one that it does. As a final note, these declarations should always end with one of the following generic families:

- Serif
- Sans-Serif
- Monospace
- Cursive
- Fantasy

Which will always have some form of implementation by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @font-face for server side fonts if u use CSS3.

As for the free font, google it, dont be lazy.

Comment: "I am using Asp.Net, css 2. Thanks"

Comment: CSS version depends on browser support, not on code. U can use CSS3 elements in ur code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific font for a title f.e. and you can't rely on CSS3, then you could render it to an image at server-side and link the image dynamically in the response HTML.

By using a filename linked to the title, you can store the image on the server in order to cache it (so you only need to render a certain title/image once).

Note that I'm mentioning 'title' here, as this is not usefull for rendering complete paragraphs :)

Answer (score 0):

The font needs to be in the user’s machine, but for this, it needs to be on a server so that the browser can be instructed to fetch it (unless the user’s machine happens to have it, which is improbable for a font like SketchFlow Print). The server need not be your server; the font could be hosted on another server, like a Google server.

Search for “@font-face” to find a suitable intro to using downloadable fonts.

You know that a font is a free font when you have a statement from the author of the font that says so. Beware that many of the “free fonts” on the web aren’t. Quick check: Does a download page mention the author of the font (and link to her or his page)?

In future, please ask separate questions separately. (The question about free fonts is quite separate from the technical issues of using downloadable fonts.)